# Change text color of cells in Account column (C# datagridview)

Tags: c#, datagridview

I'm trying to change the font color of all rows in the Account column on program load with little success. Am I doing anything wrong here?

This is my code so far:

```
private void dataGridView1_CellFormatting(object sender, DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs e)
{
    if (this.dataGridView1.Columns[e.ColumnIndex].Name == "Account")
    {
        e.CellStyle.ForeColor = Color.Blue;
    }
}
```

Comment: What's the problem here? For me it works. See my answer, you can set it once.

Comment: The font color of all the row items do not appear blue

Comment: It should work. Run in debug mode to see if you are going in this line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This this (it will color this row text with blue):

```
this.dataGridView1.Columns["Account"].DefaultCellStyle.ForeColor = Color.Blue;
```

Comment: @methuselah what's wrong with this answer? it should work as what you expect.

Answer (score 1):

Just add the following line:

```
this.previousRentDataGridViewTextBoxColumn.ItemStyle-ForeColor = <color>;
```

Comment: I get the following error - `Error: 'System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewTextBoxColumn' does not contain a definition for 'ItemStyle' and no extension method 'ItemStyle' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Windows.Forms.DataGridViewTextBoxColumn' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)`

Comment: I think this answer regarding to ASP.NET and not Winforms.
Could you provide more code and details? When do you add your rows? Dynamically?

Comment: @methuselah sorry for misleading you. In fact, as etaiso said, my answer is for ASP.NET. Didn't know your question was for Winforms.